# What transformer should I use for `gdal.Warp`?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

The documentation for `gdal.Warp` (http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#Warp) lists the following alluring options:

```
  tps --- whether to use Thin Plate Spline GCP transformer
  rpc --- whether to use RPC transformer
  geoloc --- whether to use GeoLocation array transformer
  polynomialOrder --- order of polynomial GCP interpolation
```

I'm having trouble finding information about these options. Is there a reason one would want to choose one over the other?